# syntax error, unexpected identifier "Closure", expecting variable in /PhpSpreadsheet/vendor/maennchen/zipstream-php/src/ZipStream.php on line 111

Tags: phpspreadsheet, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

The following PhpSpreadsheet code is working properly on localhost but not on live server.

THE ISSUE IS : **save('php://output'); is not downloading the xlsx file.**

PhpSpreadsheet Version : 1.29.0

PHP version is:
localhost : 8.1.6
live server : 8.0.28

```
<?php


require('PhpSpreadsheet/vendor/autoload.php');



use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border;


// WORKSHEET 1



$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setTitle('STACKOVERFLOW');


$spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Calibri')->setSize(9);


$sheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(40);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(40);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(20);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(20);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(20);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(20);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(40);



$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'UNREAL');


$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');


header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="spreadsheet.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');


$writer->save('php://output');
```

I changed :
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx'); **to** Html
and
filename="spreadsheet.xlsx" **to** spreadsheet.html

which is working fine ( file spreadsheet.html got downloaded )

**but I want xlsx format.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a known issue with PhpSpreadsheet on PHP 8.0](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/3684).

The comments on the issue on Github list some workarounds, but since PHP 8.0 is rapidly approaching [end of life](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php) anyway, you'd be better off upgrading your production environment to match your development environment.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin, updating php version to 8.1 solved my problem